# Redis smembers with node

Tags: ajax, node.js, redis

I have a `Node, Express, and Websockets` chat app. The usernames of the users currently in the chatroom is stored to `Redis`. From the `redis-cli` when I type in `SMEMBERS 'onlineUsers'`, I get back a list of all the users currently in the room:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> smembers 'onlineUsers'
 1) "jackson"
 2) "bubba yump"
 3) "dog"
 4) "rumba"
 5) "buba"
```

In my main application `javascript` file I have a method to get the current users so I can display them on the page:

```
var showCurrentUsers = function(){
    $('#list_of_users').empty();
    $.getJSON('getUsers', function(data){
        console.log(data)
        for (var i in data){
             $('#list_of_users').append("<li> User: "+data[i]+"</li>")
        }
    });
}
```

In my `Node` server file I have the matching route but `db.smembers` keeps returning `true` instead of a list of the users.

```
app.get('/getUsers', function(req,res){
   res.send(getOnlineUsers());
 });

// REDIS DATA
var getOnlineUsers = function(){
  return db.smembers("onlineUsers")
}
```

and here is where the username is originally posted to the database:

```
  client.on("setUsername", function(user){
            pub.publish("chatting","A new user in connected:" + user);
            db.sadd("onlineUsers",user);
        }
    );
```

I know that the usernames are correctly posting to the database, and I can access them from the `redis-cli`, but I'm not sure why my JSON call is returning `true` instead of the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I'm assuming you're using https://github.com/mranney/node_redis)

The node redis client is async.  You can treat it as sync for writes and deletes, but to read from the db you need to use a callback.

```
app.get('/getUsers', function(req, res, next){
   getOnlineUsers(function (err, onlineUsers) {
     if (err) {
       return next(err);
     }
     res.send(onlineUsers);
   });
 });

// REDIS DATA
var getOnlineUsers = function(cb){
  return db.smembers("onlineUsers", cb);
}
```

Comment: As a note the `db.sadd("onlineUsers",user);` can be written with a callback if you need to confirm the write succeeded eg `db.sadd("onlineUsers",user, function (err) { if (err) { handle(err); } });`

Comment: Thanks! I tried `await`, and had no luck, so I will try with a callback.