# My second promise gets called before getting the data from the first one resulting in an undefined. Not sure what I am doing

Tags: node.js, redis, callback, promise

After the underPrice function call, it goes straight to the next promise call and returns undefined, then goes to under price. I am not sure what I am doing wrong any help would be really appreciated. The data is there as undrPrice gets the keys and if I put a console.log - it prints it out. The issues is the second then statement goes off without the first one being done

```
/// grab all online
var getActiveData = (payload) => {
     pub.smembers('partner:services:' + payload.services)
      .then((data) => {
        Promise.all(data.map(underPrice.bind(this, payload)))
      })
      .then((data) => {
        Promise.all(console.log(data));
      });};
```

Here is the underPrice code

```
var underPrice = (payload, key) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    pub.hmget(key + ":services:" + payload.services, "amount", (err, data) => {
      if (err) reject(err); //will display '1, 3, 5, 7'
      else {
        data <= payload.price ? resolve(key) : reject(key);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: You're not calling `resolve()` or `reject()` for your first promise there. Do you even need to use `new Promise` there? Does `pup.smembers()` return a promise?

Comment: pub.smembers is a redis function. I removed the return new promise statement from pub.smembers. I still get an undefined call. 


I am fairly new to promises. The getActiveData was supposed to return a promise to the original call. I change the code and removed the promise call but I still get an undefined.

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redis smembers with node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459070/redis-smembers-with-node)

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I looked into that but that’s not the case as I can print those values

Comment: Can you point to somewhere in the documentation that says `pub.smembers()` is thenable? I have looked but failed to find it.

Comment: You are correct. I looked at the ioredis and its says under basic usage https://github.com/luin/ioredis

 
    

So basically I need to call functions inside?

Comment: Yes, it looks that way and if so I expect that Bergi's answer offers only a part solution. Could leave him a comment indicating whether it works or not?

Comment: Haven’t tried it yet but that’s the first thing I will once I get home and reply :)

Comment: If Bergi's code works, then `pub.smembers()`, must be thenable and there's a good chance that `pub.hmget()` is also thenable. If so, `underprice()` will simplify to `return pub.hmget(...).then(...);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting to `return` the promises from your functions, especially from the `then` callbacks, so the caller will have nothing to wait for.

```
function getActiveData(payload) {
    return pub.smembers('partner:services:' + payload.services)
//  ^^^^^^
    .then(data => {
        return Promise.all(data.map(underPrice.bind(this, payload)))
//      ^^^^^^
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        return data;
//      ^^^^^^
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks that helped.

Comment: Another question regarding - in the underPrice function I am performing an if statement where it should only return keys that match case. So when I do resolve(keys) if it matches and null if it doesn’t. I don’t get anything back l... any idea how I can get that done ? Thank you

Comment: You still need to always resolve the promise, even if with a `null` value